# How to move to previous caret position?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

How can one move to previous caret position(s) in Android Studio?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>

For Mac, use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>

If these don't work for you, it is possible that these keys are assigned for some of the functions of your OS/video drivers, you can either disable the shortcuts that are using these keys from operating system settings/video driver settings or change shortcuts from Android Studio itself by going to:

```
File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > Navigate > Back/Forward
```

[image: Move to previous caret position Android Studio]

Mac users can find this dialog by going to Android Studio's: `App Menu -> Preferences`

Comment: Does anyone knows how to navigate(back/forward) using swipe gesture from Apple mouse? I really need this.

Comment: Just want to add, android studio also shows which actions are using the same key combination when you click on any action in keymap and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`. So you don't have to search through every keymap setting to find out which other keymaps are using the same combination.

Answer (score 56):

It's `Alt + Ctrl + Right/Left arrow` and mouse buttons 4 and 5 (if your mouse has those). You can change these shortcuts under:

`File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > Navigate > Back/Forward`.

Comment: On Ubuntu these shortcuts move around virtual workspaces, so they are captured by the window manager before they get to AS. You may be having similar problems on your platform.

Comment: As @michael mention on Ubuntu this keys are captured by system. If you go to Setting > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation and change these keys these keys will start to work.

Comment: In Windows you may find those keys flip the display orientation, so you'll have to disable the shortcuts: Right-click on your desktop, select Graphics Options > Hot Keys > Disable

Comment: Am I on same planet as you are? `Alt + Ctrl + Right/Left arrow` rotate the window in Windows for me!

Comment: Yes, those shortcuts are interfering, so you have to either change it in IDEA or disable the annoying window rotation shortcut.

Comment: Does anyone knows how to navigate(back/forward) using swipe gesture from Apple mouse? I really need this

Answer (score 14):

In **Android Studio**, go to View and check the ToolBar option. It will show the Back and Forward buttons.

`cmd + [ and cmd + ]` will move your caret to the previous and next positions.

Confirmed on Android Studio v2.3.3 / MacOS

Use `Ctrl + Alt + Left and Ctrl + Alt + Right`

For Mac, use `Command + Option + Left and Command + Option + Right`

If these don't work for you, it is possible that these keys are assigned for some of the functions of your OS/video drivers, you can either disable the shortcuts that are using these keys from operating system settings/video driver settings or change shortcuts from Android Studio itself by going to:

`File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > Navigate > Back/Forward`

Mac users can find this dialog by going to Android Studio's: `App Menu -> Preferences`

For **Windows/Linux** : `Ctrl + Alt + Left / Right`

For **Mac** : `Cmd + Alt + Left / Right`

Another option : move to the last edit location: `CTRL + SHIFT + BACKSPACE`

Move to the last cursor position: `CTRL + ALT + left Arrow`

`cmd + [ and cmd + ]` will move your caret to the previous and next positions.

Confirmed on Android Studio v3.0.1 / MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3

**Ubuntu 19-04** (Gnome)

navigate back = `alt + shift + left`

navigate forwards = `alt + shift + right`

[**Source**](https://code-examples.net/en/q/1bb6513)

Answer (score 13):

- Another option : move to the last edit location: **CTRL + SHIFT + BACKSPACE**
- Move to the last cursor position: **CTRL + ALT + left Arrow**

Comment: This answer worked in my `Android Studio 1.4.1` and not the previous answer. @AVEbrahimi A useful link for the tips and tricks of moving around in `Android Studio` : http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-tricks-moving-around/

Comment: CTRL + ALT + left Arrow, rotate the screen of the LCD.

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad: this is also the shortcut of the display driver. You should disalbe the shortcut of display driver.
ref: https://superuser.com/questions/279756/how-to-disable-the-screen-orientation-hotkeys-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use keyboard shortcuts, goto view >> Toolbar and check it (if its unchecked) as shown below

[image]

Doing this will add two shortcuts below menu options to navigate forward and backward like shown below

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

Starting Android Studio Giraffe we can opt for the new UI.
In the new UI, the toolbar is removed and we no longer see the forward and back button. We need to bring them by customizing the toolbar.

Steps:

1. Right click on the top toolbar and click on Customize toolbar.

[image]

2. In the new dialog box, click on the plus icon and select Add action.
   You can add separator as well depending upon where you want to bring
   those icons.

[image]

3. From the new dialog, now we can select the actions that we want to
   be appeared. Select Main Menu -> Navigate and Back. And one more
   same step for Forward. Then once applied, we can see the arrows in
   our favorite place.

[image]

---

In earlier Android Studio versions, to enable back arrow on toolbar, go to:

View -> Appearance -> Toolbar

Answer (score 2):

For those coming from Eclipse, you can have Android Studio use Eclipse style keyboard mappings.  Keep in mind host OS can still intercept keystrokes and prevent some keystrokes from working as desired in both Eclipse and Android Studio. If you want to give it a try, here is where to switch it:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, go to View and check the ToolBar option. It will show the Back and Forward buttons.

Answer (score 2):

## In MacOS

Go to Preferences -> Keymap,
Confirm that you have `macOS` selected in dropdown.

Now go back to editor, press `cmd + [` or `cmd + ]` to navigate.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In Android Studio BumbleBee | 2021.1.1,
Just Click

> View -> Appearance -> Check Toolbar

And you will see a right and left array to navigate

Answer (score 1):

cmd + [ and cmd + ] will move your caret to the previous and next positions.

Confirmed on Android Studio v3.0.1 / MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> will move your caret to the previous and next positions.

Confirmed on Android Studio v2.3.3 / MacOS

Answer (score 0):

For Windows/Linux : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>

For Mac : <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 19-04 (Gnome)

navigate back = <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>

navigate forwards = <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd>